# Google Photos API Bad Request

Tags: google-photos-api

This was working fine with the same code until 13/2/2024.
Now its just broken with Bad Request:

```
Client error: `POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

The actual API connects and shows scope as

[image]

The other API calls work just fine.

The code calls the simple service function

```
listAlbums()
```

UPDATE:
after having left it, the exact same code functions again. It seems there is a delay everytime a new token is created. Surely a token should be ready to use straight away ?